# how to grep file name checking with extension and store in a array using perl

Tags: perl

we have some pdf file in a directory

```
abc.pdf20200623
chg.pdf20200624
guih.pdf20200614
```

I want to grep all those .pdf file and store it in a array.below is the sample code.

Below code is not working to find the pdf file from the dir, I think grep is not working, what's the possible solution for this problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict
my sent_dir = "/abc/sfj/gjj";
opendir(DIR, "sent_dir");
my @file_local = grep(/\.pdf$/i,readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR)
```

Comment: there is no extension `pdf` in your inputs

Comment: instead adding `date values` in pdf

Comment: @ssr1012 I want to match the middle part of the file name like '.pdf' part.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 4):

This is what [`glob()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) is for.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sent_dir = '/abc/sfj/gjj';

my @files = glob "$sent_dir/*pdf*";
```

Answer (score 1):

In your input files there is no `extension *.pdf`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = "C:\\test";

opendir(DIR, "$dir") || die "Couldn't find the dir $dir: $!\n";
my @allpdffiles = grep /\.pdf([\d\-]+)?$/i, readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

print join "\n", @allpdffiles;

Output:

test1.pdf123  
test2.pdf456  
test3.pdf789
```

Comment: grep /\.pdf(\d+)?$/i logic is not working,after running this logic ,i did not get any output

Comment: As per the input the above code will run. Pls provide your input which doesn't work

Comment: Sample Input file name - abc used out san.pdf06-30-2020

Comment: `abc.pdf20200623` this is your old input in your question.. `abc.pdf20200623` includes hyphen in your new input.. sure my code doesn't work changing the input pattern...

Comment: Please check now I have updated the answer